# Interpretation of this Diagnostic Plot for Linear Regression

Tags: python, r, linear-regression, diagnostic-tools

I understand what are the four plots for but I am not very good at interpreting diagnostic plot.. Especially this one. Any help is greatly appreciated. What you can say about the 4 plots here in relation to 1) Linearity 2) Error are normally distributed 3) homoscedasticity 4) influential outliers

[image: Diagnostic Plot]

Comment: For me, the assumption of linearity and normally distributed error does not look so good (plot 1 and 3)....

Comment: I think these show some good evidence against linearity, homoscedasticity and normally distributed residuals I'm afraid.